# Exponentiating a matrix

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

I was just wondering whether my solution is correct or not and if it isn't, where I went wrong?

Find $ e^A $ where $ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0  
\end{bmatrix} $

So what I did is I saw that

$$ e^A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}^{n}}{n!}$$

and I figured out that when n is even, the resulting matrix is the identity matrix and when n is odd it just turns out to be A itself, so now I transformed it into

$$ e^A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1   \\
    1 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}}{2n!}   +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0   \\
    0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}}{(2n+1)!} $$
after this I don't really know what to do, they look similar to the power series of cos and sin though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ is an order-$2$ permutation matrix, hence:

$$ e^{A}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{A^n}{n!} = A\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{I}{(2n+1)!}+I\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{I}{(2n)!} = \sinh(1) A + \cosh(1) I = \begin{pmatrix}\cosh(1)&\sinh(1)\\\sinh(1)&\cosh(1)\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2e}\begin{pmatrix}e^2+1&e^2-1\\e^2-1&e^2+1\end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Instead of $\cos$ and $\sin$, think $\cosh$ and $\sinh$. These hyperbolic trig functions have almost the same expansion, except each term is positive.